# Highlighting popup section using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Here is my code, but still i am not getting an ouput what i expect.

```
<head>
    <script>
        function overlay()
        {
            $("body").css ({
                "background" : "#fff",
                "z-index"    : "999",
                "opacity"    : "0.50",
                "position"   : "relative",
            });
            $("#popupContact").css ({
                "position"   : "relative",
                "z-index" : "999",
                "opacity"    : "1"
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="popupContact">
       <h1>Sample Test</h1>
   </div>
<a onclick="return overlay();">Click to view</a>
</body>
```

If i click on that `<a>` , a popup window will be open , in that time i want to show popup division as highlighted and body should be dim..

Any useful answer will be really appreciate..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on how to create fancy popups some time ago, let me know if you want to see it..

Comment: I already done fancy box.. but i want to highlight that section to users. Thats it...

Comment: yes please post here..

Comment: I am not sure I understand your post, but you can try this, hope it gives you idea http://www.anchorx.com/ali/2011/03/16/jquery-popup-without-a-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your child div `popupContact` is inheriting `body` opacity

So one of the possible workarounds is to use this instead of `background:#fff`

use this `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`

```
<head>
    <script>
    function overlay()
    {
        $("body").css ({
            "background-color" : "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
            "z-index"    : "999",
            "position"   : "relative",
        });
        $("#popupContact").css ({
            "background-color" : "rgba(200,200,200,1)",
            "position"   : "relative",
            "z-index" : "9919",
            "opacity"    : "1"
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="popupContact">
       <h1>Sample Test</h1>
   </div>
<a onclick="return overlay();">Click to view</a>
</body>
```

Here is a link for the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/XFn67/

Comment: use this please background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

Comment: increase the popupContact z-index or decrease the body z-index

Answer (score 0):

You could add some sort of container div 'below' your popup, using z-indexes. So you end up with something like this:

```
<div id="popupContainer"></div>
<div id="popupContact">
    <h1>Sample Test</h1>
</div>
<a onclick="return overlay();">Click to view</a>
```

The popupContainer and popupContact ids should have some css properties to fill the whole screen and put the popup above the container.

```
#popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
}

#popupContact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  z-index: 11;
}
```

And the `overlay` function should be changed to something like:

```
function overlay() {
  $('#popupContainer, #popupContact').toggle();
}
```

Comment: I changed the position of body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "background-color" also you have a trailing comma there.